# Make snippet comment tags start and end on their own line separate from text

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-snippets

When you add or edit a snippet, the start and end comment tags get jammed up against the text of the question/answer. They should be on their own line, ideally separated from the other text by a line break.

E.g., not:

> here's an example:<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false -->
>   
> ...
>   
> <!-- end snippet -->What we've done there is...

but instead:

> here's an example:
>   
>   
> <!-- begin snippet: js hide: false -->
>   
> ...
>   
> <!-- end snippet -->
>   
>   
> What we've done there is...

Interestingly, this is what happens here on MSE, but not on SO. Perhaps MSE is using a more up-to-date version of Stack Snippets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for bringing this issue up. It was fixed in a previous build and this is now working as expected.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I thought I'd deleted this when I found it was suddenly working. As far as I can tell, it literally got rolled out to SO *as* I was reporting it here. :-)

Comment: No problem at all. I think you're right re: timing of this post.